# Iterating through a List that is filled with arrays in C#

Tags: c#

```
        public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
    {
        List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                string[] row;
                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    row = line.Split(',');
                    parsedData.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return parsedData;
    }
```

I want to use this code to parse a CSV, and this returns a List filled with arrays.  My question is how do I iterate through the arrays within the list if they are of unknown size?

for example:

```
for (int a=0; a<=CSVList(firstindex).Length;a++)
         for (int a=0; a<=CSVList(secondindex).Length;a++)
```

Something like this would read the first index of the CSVList and then the first array element in it...I think I am just really stuck on the syntax.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ to flatten this out, if you just want to write out each value:

```
var results = parseCSV(path);

foreach(var str in results.SelectMany(i => i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Otherwise, you can do this in two loops:

```
var results = parseCSV(path);
foreach(var arr in results)
{
    for (int i=0;i<arr.Length;++i) // Loop through array
    {
        string value = arr[i]; // This is the array element...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a `List<string[]>` values then the simplest syntax is nested foreach loops.

```
foreach (var arrayElement in CSVList) {
  foreach (var current in arrayElement) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be much better off using `foreach` loops, rather than classical `for` loops.

With `foreach` your iteration is written:

```
foreach(string[] array in parsedData) {
    foreach(string element in array) {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

With `foreach` you just say “iterate over *all the elements*”, you need not worry about *how many* elments there are.

Answer (score 0):

Each array will have a size because all arrays in .NET inherit from `System.Array`.  Simply reference the array based on the list index and then you can simply iterate to `MyArrayOfInterest.count-1`

Comment: Right, my question is more the syntax of c# and iterating through a list of arrays